# How to search by byte array in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have an Entity called User and It has a byte array field. What I want to query is get all users with specific sessionId.

```
@Entity
public class User{
    ....

    @Column(name = "session_id")
    private byte[] sessionId;

}
```

I have created a Dao method like below but is this the correct way to query binary data? I can convert this binary data to UTF8 String and store it as varchar but I don't know which way is more efficient?

```
public List<User> getAllUsers(byte[] sessionId){
    EntityManager entityManager = (EntityManager) session.getSession();
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE session_id = ?1");
    query.setParameter(1, sessionId);
    ....
}
```

Comment: Is there any additional use of having a byte[] session ID? Is it not a String or is it used in a different context as a byte[]?

Comment: @Smutje We need to call an API method and It takes session ID as byte array. So I need to convert it to byte array even I keep it as String in DB.

Comment: I'd say it doesn't matter which representation you save from a performance point of view, I would depend the decision on things like readability or traceability and the amount of times I need to convert it between different representations.

Comment: What data type is best here depends on the database and what indexes you've created for the table. It's irrelevant to the JPA.